# Is it worth is to get a headset with AAC codec for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, music, apple-music

I'm considering getting a wireless headset for my iPhone (and the upcoming iPhone). During my search, I found that some of Bang & Olufsen headsets are supporting AAC codec, such as  H5 and H7.

Does it worth to get a headset with AAC codec considering that AAC is an Apple standard?

Is there a noticeable difference between a headset that supports AAC codec and a one that doesn't?

I'm an Apple Music user.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say whether it is worth it as it highly subjective.

A headset with AAC codec support will be able to receive audio at a higher quality than the alternative SBC codec at similar bit rates.

The question is whether you are able to hear the difference in sound quality, and if that translates into enough value for you that you're willing to pay a premium for it.

So basically, if you're into high quality audio - go for the AAC support. If you don't care, you're probably not going to notice the difference between AAC and SBS anyway.

Comment: Even if the headseat is able to receive AAC encoded audio, the question is still whether the iPhone can send it.

Comment: The iPhone support sending AAC encoded audio over Bluetooth, and has done so for years.